# What is the proof that the 2 angles in a cyclic trapezium on one of the parallel lines are equal?

Tags: geometry

I will define trapezium ABCD as a cyclic quadrilateral with sides AB and CD being parallel. A tangent touches C.

How do I prove that angle D = C as A = B?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

The common perpendicular bisector of the two parallel sides is a symmetry axis of the figure.

Answer (score 1):

hint: $\newcommand{arc}[1]{\stackrel{\Large\frown}{#1}}\arc{AD}=\arc{BC}$ (parallel chords create congruent arcs). Use this to prove that $\angle{D} \cong \angle{C}$. Then use the fact that in cyclic quadrilateral opposite angles are supplementary.